# Trouble with Guessing the Number Game in C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a random number guessing game in school. This is only my second week programming so this assignment has been challenging for me to say the least. I think I have everything down except my loop must be broken somewhere (I can't find it!) because it never identifies a correct answer - just states every guess is wrong.  What have I done?? I'm hoping you can help me :) Much appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assn3_2
{
class Program
{
    public static int SelectedNumber = 0;
    public static Random ran = new Random();
    public static bool GameOver = false;
    public static int UserMaxValue = 0;



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int UserNumber;
        SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
            UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please make a guess between 1 and {0}", UserMaxValue);
                UserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                GuessNumber(UserNumber);

            } while (GameOver == false);
        } while (GameOver == false);
    }

    public static void GuessNumber(int UserNumber)

    {
        int playagain = 0;

        if (UserNumber < SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong. Please try again.");
        else if (UserNumber > SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong.Please try again.");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct! The number is {0}. Again? (1 or 2)");
            playagain = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());;

            while (playagain != 1 && playagain !=2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Again? Y or N");
                playagain = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (playagain.Equals(2))
                GameOver = true;

            else
                SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);
        }


    }
}


}
```

Comment: Ok, you wrote some code.  Now, it is time to debug it.  Set Breakpoints, examine variables and watch the code execute line by line.

Comment: I guess it must be working wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);
```

You run this **BEFORE** you prompt the user to fill in a value for `UserMaxValue`, so effectively you're doing

```
 SelectNumber = ran.Next(0, 0);
```

Not very random, when there's only one choice, and that choice being `0`... especially when you only allow guesses between `1` and the Max value that gets provided later.

Comment: Thank you so much Marc B!! I made that change and a random number other than "0" was created! 

Now, my only other issue is that instead of looping back to my first 'do' statement (setting the maximum value) my program just asks the user to guess within the same range of values. Does anyone have any suggestions or hints on how to change that?

Comment: @VictoriaN  Will this Q&A iterate till you fix all your bugs? One question at a time please....

Comment: And this isn't a debugging service. The **MOST** important part of learning how to code, is learning how to debug. If you don't even TRY to figure things out on your own, you learn nothing.

Comment: True true! Again thanks for the help :) I'll trouble shoot the rest and work on these coding skills!